# How do I go about allowing a user to input as many strings as they want while also checking it against an array?

Tags: java, arrays, input, user-input

I am doing this assignment for my CSCI 1301 class and i'm kinda stuck.
The assignment is to write a program that will provide a list of services to users and allow them to choose any or all services they would like and display the final price.
Here's my code so far,

```
public static void carMaintenance()
{
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

String makeOfCar;

System.out.println("What's the make of your car?");
makeOfCar = sc.next();

String[] services = {"Oil Change", "Tire Rotation", "Air Filter", "Fluid Check"};

double[] prices = {39.99, 49.99, 19.99, 10.99};

System.out.println("What services whould you like for your "+makeOfCar+"?");
System.out.println(services[0]+", "+services[1]+", "+services[2]+", "+services[3]+".");
}
```

Where i'm stuck at is how would I go about allowing the user to request as many services they want?(Logically speaking, they can only request up to 4 services)

I figured I could use another array and put it in a "do-while" loop to achieve this but then, once I check it against the "services" array how would I assign a price to each service the user requested so that I can calculate the total price for all requested services?

any insight and help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Arrays have limited sizes... You should use an arraylist to endlessly ask for input... In any case, add your attempts at using some while loop

Comment: You're missing the fact that Java is an OO language. You shouldn't have an array of service names, and an array of prices. You should have an array of Service objects, and a Service should have a name and a price. Using collections (List, Set) would also make things easier than using arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep track of the sum in an extra variable. So your idea with the extra array to check for duplicates would still work. Check if the service is already chosen and if not, add the chosen index to the sum.

```
public static void carMaintenance() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String makeOfCar;

    System.out.println("What's the make of your car?");
    makeOfCar = sc.nextLine();

    String[] services = {"Oil Change", "Tire Rotation", "Air Filter", "Fluid Check"};

    double[] prices = {39.99, 49.99, 19.99, 10.99};
    double sum = 0;


    System.out.println("What services whould you like for your " + makeOfCar + "?");
    System.out.println(services[0] + ", " + services[1] + ", " + services[2] + ", " + services[3] + ".");

    String choice;

    //This array simply tracks true or false for chosen/not chosen. boolean arrays are initialized with all values false.
    boolean[] chosenServices = new boolean[services.length]; //Can only be as many elements as there are services. This way you don't have to change it when you add another service
    do {
        choice = sc.nextLine();

        int choiceIndex = getIndex(services, choice);
        if (choiceIndex < 0) break; //Choice doesn't exist. You will have to refine that and add messages

        if (!chosenServices[choiceIndex]) { //service not yet chosen
            chosenServices[choiceIndex] = true;
            sum += prices[choiceIndex];
        } else {
            System.out.println("Was already chosen!");
        }

    } while (!choice.toLowerCase().equals("exit")); //Or something similar

    System.out.printf("%.2f", sum); //Price with 2 digits 

}

public static int getIndex(String[] arr, String search) {
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (search.equals(arr[i]))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

As mentioned in one of the comments, this is only a rough implementation. You might want to do this with index input from the user, you might want to check for false inputs more precise than I did here etc. but that should do what I think you mean.

Comment: Thank you this helped me greatly and I received a 100 on the assignment thanks to your insight cheers!!